# Mean and std dev. of large set of data using recursion

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have a large set of data .

Then I can divide it into two find mean of those two and calculate the mean of the last 2 values I get.

a) Is this the mean of the original big quantity ?

b) Can I do this sort of method for calculating standard deviation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) only if the sets you divide into are always the same size, meaning that the original set size must be a power of 2.

For example, the mean of {6} is 6, and the mean of {3,6} is 4.5, but the mean of {3,6,6} is not 5.25, it's 5.

Certainly you could recursively divide into parts to calculate the sum, though, and divide by the total size at the end. Not sure if that does you any good.

b) no

For example, the s.d of {2} is 0, and the s.d. of {1} is 0, but the s.d of {1,2} is not 0.

Once you've calculated the mean of the whole set, you can recursively divide to calculate the sum square deviation from the mean, and as with the mean calculation, divide by the total size and take square root at the end. [Edit: in fact all you need to calculate s.d is the sumsquare, the sum, and the count. Forgot about that. So you don't have to calculate the mean first]

Comment: "only if the sets you divide into are always the same size"  Wikipedia seems to disagree; see my answer.

Comment: @Ishtar: but when you multiply the means by the element counts, you're just extracting the sums back out, which is what I already said. I don't think it's worth a semantic argument over whether that "counts" or not.

Comment: Extracting the approximate sums (with rounding-related errors) back out.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Oops, overlooked the exact context of the question. I meant to say, it *is* possible to combine means and standard deviations. I do agree that it'll do you no good as an algorithm.

Comment: @Ishtar: yep, it's possible if you have extra information as well as just the mean/s.d of the two subsets. My "only if" was intended to answer "is the mean of the subset means equal to the mean of the full set", rather than "is it possible to calculate the mean by some process that involves a recursive function somewhere" :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect, but if you *can* express the mean and standard deviation of a set from the means, standard deviations, and size of the sets which that set is divided into.

Specifically, if m_x, s_x and n_x are the means, standard deviations, and sizes of x, and X is partitioned into many x's, then

```
n_X = sum_x(n_x)
m_X = sum_x(n_x m_x)/n_X
s_X^2 = (sum_x(n_x(s_x^2 + m_x^2)) - m_X)/n_X
```

assuming the standard deviation is of the form sum(x - mean(x))/n; if it is the sample unbiased estimator, just adjust the weights accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On (a) - it's only precisely correct if you precisely divided the set into two. If there were an odd number of items, for instance, there is a slight weighting toward the smaller "half". The larger the set, the less significant the problem. However, the problem recurs for the smaller sets as you subdivide. You get very large error when dividing a set of three items into a single item and a pair - each item in the pair is only half as significant to the final result as the single item.

I don't see the gain, though. You still do as many additions. You even end up doing more divisions. More importantly, you access memory in a non-sequential order, leading to poor cache performance.

The usual approach for a mean and standard deviation is to first calculate the sum of all items, and the sum of the squares - both in the same loop. Old calculators used to handle this with running totals, also keeping count of the number of items as they went. At the end, those three values (n, sum-of-x and sum-of-x-squared) are all you need - the rest is just substitution into the standard formulae for the mean and standard deviation.

**EDIT**

If you're dead set on using recursion for this, look up "tail recursion". Mathematically, tail recursion and iteration are equivalent - different representations of the same thing. In implementation terms tail recursion might cause a stack overflow where iteration would work, but (1) some languages guarantee this will not happen (e.g. Scheme, Haskell), and (2) many compilers will handle this as an optimisation anyway (e.g. GCC for C or C++).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. No need for equal sets, power of two. Pseudo code:

```
N1,mean1,s1;
N2,mean2,s2;
N12,mean12,s12;

N12 = N1+N2;
mean12 = ((mean1*N1) + (mean2*N2)) / N12;
s12 = sqrt( (s1*s1*N1 + s2*s2*N2) / N12 + N1*N2/(N12*N12)*(s1-s2)*(s1-s2) );
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Combining_standard_deviations